# Python image sequence file concatenation

Tags: python, python-2.x

I need to iterate over a large (in the thousands) list of files in a network folder and "concatenate" any image sequences into just one entry with the range of images (first image, last image in sequence). I am calling this "sequence pruning" and I created the following code which does work, but it seems incredibly un-pythonic to me and runs slowly. I'm certain there is a MUCH better way to do this, so I am looking for review to help clean/speed this up.

To elaborate a bit further on the issue lets say I have this as a list of files for the input:

```
img.001.png
img.002.png
img.003.png
img_other.001.png
random_file.txt
yet another seq.0000.png
yet another seq.0001.png
yet another seq.0002.png
yet another seq.0021.png
yet another seq.0030.png
```

In the end I want to return something like this:

```
img.001.png, [1-3]
img_other.001.png
random_file.txt
yet another seq.0000.png, [0-30]
```

FYI I can safely assume that the image sequence number is always going to be a series of digits at the very end of the filename (before the extension of course). However I cannot assume that they will be perfectly sequential, as there are sometimes "gaps" between numbers.

Here's my current code, python 2.7:

```
import os

def split_padding(path):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
    pad_int = 0

    while file[pad_int * -1 - 1].isdigit():
        pad_int += 1

    if pad_int == 0:
        return file, '0', ext

    clean_file = file[0:pad_int * -1]
    padding = file[pad_int * -1:]

    return clean_file, padding, ext

def strip_padding(path):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(path)

    while file[-1].isdigit():
        file = file[:-1]

    return file

def prune_files(paths):
    '''
    sequences get put into arrays like so:
    [x_folder, z_folder, [test_a.000.png, 0, 2], [test_b.000.tif, 0, 3], test_C.000.png]
    :return: [file1, file2, [first_file, seq_start, seq_end]]
    '''
    paths.sort(key=lambda s: s.lower()) # list has to be sorted for this to work

    # this odd bit of code turns all sequences into arrays of images.
    pruned_list = []
    switch = True
    for c, path in enumerate(paths):
        if c == 0:
            pruned_list.append(path)
            continue
        if not os.path.splitext(path)[1] in ['.png', '.tif', '.tiff', '.exr', '.jpg', '.jpeg']:
            pruned_list.append(path)
            continue

        test = paths[c-1]
        if strip_padding(path) == strip_padding(test):
            if switch:
                pruned_list[-1] = [pruned_list[-1]]
                switch = False
            pruned_list[-1].append(path)
        else:
            pruned_list.append(path)
            switch = True

    # so now lets convert that to the format we want to return
    for c, item in enumerate(pruned_list):
        if type(item) == list:
            pruned_list[c] = [item[0], int(split_padding(item[0])[1]), int(split_padding(item[-1])[1])]

    return pruned_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_dir = "some directory"
    print prune_files([path for path in os.listdir(test_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(test_dir, path))])
```

Comment: Can you assume the numbers will be sorted at all? Is it possible that 'img.003.png' comes after 'random_file.txt', or are the file names sorted alphabetically too?

Comment: The input list comes from os.listdir(), so I get whatever that returns. From my experience it isn't always sorted so I opted to do my own sort in the beginning of my prune_files def. I realize that was perhaps confusing in my example, so I just fixed it!

Comment: I'm just playing around a bit to see how performance could be improved, and noticed `prune_files()` currently does not take into account file extensions, only name and sequence numbers. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: @Coal_ Ha that would explain an error I got yesterday. No, not really intended so I'll have to fix that. As a note I found that looping through the list and stripping out the sequence numbers, then converting to a set to remove duplicates is a very rapid way of getting rid of everything but one entry per sequence. However at that point you still don't have first and last file...

Comment: It would now be best to ask a new question with the changes incorporated, since you have accepted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many, many problems:

- Low level dealing with strings. Python is a high-level programming language - don't reinvent the wheel. Regex and string methods now are replacing your low-level code in my rework of it. Good rule of thumb is to avoid any code that has a lot of array indexing in Python.
- Sorting doesn't need a function if you use `sorted`
- Long comprehensions and generators are usually unreadable and unmaintainable so avoid those at all costs. Especially avoid adding needless logic in them too.
- Extension list is a constant so you might as well extract that to the top.
- Simpler or more standard output could have made the code much simpler but it wasn't clear if that was the requirement.
- Hardcoding args shouldn't be done when `sys.argv` and `argparse` are so easy to use.

tl;dr fixed code. Code could be a lot simpler if the output format was a bit more standard but you can probably modify the code with minimal effort:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import re
import sys

FILE_EXTS = [
    'exr',
    'jpeg',
    'jpg',
    'png',
    'tif',
    'tiff',
]

SEQUENCE_PATTERN = r'(.*)\.([0-9]+).(.{3,4})$'

def sequences_strigifier(sequences):
    output_string = ''
    for key, seq_info in sequences.items():
        if not seq_info:
            output_string += '{}\n'.format(key)
            continue

        if seq_info['start_index'] == seq_info['end_index']:
            output_string += '{}.{}.{}\n'.format(key,
                                                 seq_info['start_index_str'],
                                                 seq_info['ext'])
            continue

        output_string += '{}.{}.{}, [{}-{}]\n'.format(key,
                                                      seq_info['start_index_str'],
                                                      seq_info['ext'],
                                                      seq_info['start_index'],
                                                      seq_info['end_index'])

    return output_string.strip()

def find_image_sequences(directory):
    '''
    sequences get put into arrays like so:
    [x_folder, z_folder, [test_a.000.png, 0, 2], [test_b.000.tif, 0, 3], test_C.000.png]
    :return: [file1, file2, [first_file, seq_start, seq_end]]
    '''
    sequences = {}

    sorted_candidate_list = sorted(os.listdir(directory))

    for candidate_path in sorted_candidate_list:
        full_candidate_path = os.path.join(directory, candidate_path)
        if not os.path.isfile(full_candidate_path):
            sequences[candidate_path] = None
            continue

        matches = re.match(SEQUENCE_PATTERN, candidate_path)
        if not matches:
            sequences[candidate_path] = None
            continue

        filename = matches.group(1)
        sequence_index = matches.group(2)
        extension = matches.group(3)

        if not extension in FILE_EXTS:
            sequences[candidate_path] = None
            continue

        if not filename in sequences:
            sequences[filename] = {
               'ext': extension,
               'start_index_str': sequence_index,
               'start_index': int(sequence_index),
               'end_index': int(sequence_index),
            }
            continue

        sequences[filename]['end_index'] = int(sequence_index)

    return sequences_strigifier(sequences)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('Usage: {} <dirname>'.format(sys.argv[0]))
        exit(1)

    print(find_image_sequences(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: Just a note that for a large set, the stringifier will be pretty slow so I would either print directly out of there or use join()/StringIO.

Comment: @Coal_ re usage format: Indeed. fixed! Good point on the exit as well.

Comment: Thanks Srdjan, lots of improvement! Sorry if I was unclear about the usage of this code, I do not want a string as the output so the stringifier part is unnecessary (dictionary works for me). And sys.arv is not needed because this being used as a module within my larger program, and will be called directly. I took your code with some tweaks and inserted it into my original Q, let me know what you think. The use of a dictionary for 'sequences', and regex, definitely cleans things up! However this runs only a tad faster than my original code, any ideas to speed it up?

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 5 → 3.

Comment: @Spencer you can only get marginal improvements here if you continue working in Python by using multiprocessing to eval each filename or maybe using an alternative interpreter like PyPy. If you want much faster performance, sadly I think your only way is to go down a level and do it in C/C++.

Comment: I just ran into one more thing. With the Regex, it is not always the case that there is a '.' before the image sequence number. In fact it could be anything... or nothing. So the only sure way to know that it is an image sequence is counting digits backwards from the extension. I'm quite new to Regex, any help on how to do that?

Comment: @Spencer You should be able to just remove the dot from the matcher regex with `r'(.*)([0-9]+).(.{3,4})$'` in that case I think but I didn't test it.

Comment: Thanks Srdjan, that didn't quite work but I'm hoping to put some more work into this later today and I'm sure I can figure it out.

Comment: For the record I posted this regex problem on SO and got some good answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311032/python-image-sequence-file-pattern-regex/50311188#50311188

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it working :)